# Devo utilizar rotas ou controllers em Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel, laravel-rotas

Sou iniciante no Laravel e tenho dúvidas sobre a utilização dos *controllers*, leio vários exemplos/tutoriais e vejo a grande maioria utiliza as *rotas* por exemplo para um requisição do formulário, pra exibir páginas, até mesmo consultas ao banco.

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação e me deparei com a seguinte situação:

**app\routes.php**

```php
Route::group(array('as'=>'aluno', 'prefix' => 'aluno', 'before' => 'auth'), function() {
// (redireciona para o dashboard) 
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return Redirect::to('aluno/dashboard');
});

// página principal - aluno/dashboard - (app/views/aluno/dashboard.blade.php)
Route::get('dashboard', function()
{
    return View::make('aluno.dashboard');
    });
});
```

**controllers\AlunoController.php**

```php
class AlunoController extends BaseController {
    public function getIndex() {
        $this->getDashboard();
    }

    public function getDashboard() {
        return View::make('aluno/dashboard');
    }
}
```

Ambas realizam a mesma função, minha dúvida é, qual devo utilizar? Rotas ou Controllers? Porque?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Geralmente, os tutoriais que você encontra pela internet demonstram projetos pequenos, ou apenas trechos de código. Nesses casos, como a necessidade de organização e de padrões de projetos é pouca, quem os escreve geralmente faz todas as formas possíveis para demonstrar a existência dessas possibilidades.

Se você quer fazer um projeto seu, recomendo que você siga um padrão que você - e sua equipe - goste mais, que consiga organizar e consiga ler e dar manutenção sem se estressar.

Assim como os muitos padrões de codificação que existem que você deve escolher qual vai adotar como, por exemplo, o PSR ou PECL, você pode escolher qual a forma que te agrada.

EU prefiro colocar tudo nos controllers.
Tenho um amigo que, se o método do controller tiver até 3 linhas, ele escreve no Router.

Novamente, fica a seu critério e de seu time.

Comment: Concordo com essa resposta. O errado é só uma questão de perspectiva. Acho que no arquivo de rotas é aceitável você fazer redirecionamentos etc, se passar disso, se começar a envolver a lógica da aplicação, é melhor pensar em usar um controlador (para despachar). Desta forma, você estará até melhor preparado para no futuro poder "escalar" a funcionalidade em questão.

Comment: Também faço assim, colocando tudo em _controllers_ separados para cada página/programa.

Answer (score 2):

Não sou nenhum Expert em Laravel mas pelo que vi até hoje sobre o framework e sobre programação, a organização deve ser um dos pontos a se observar, então tenho por mim que não misturar as rotas com a logica da aplicação deva ser a melhor escolha mesmo que custe algumas linhas de codigo a mais em seu projeto.

Answer (score -1):

Depende.

Copio e colo abaixo o atual `routes.php` de um projeto em desenvolvimento.

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

/*** "STATIC" SITE ***/
Route::group(array(), function()
{
    Route::get('/', 'GuestController@index');
    Route::get('/franqueado', 'GuestController@franqueado');
    Route::controller('home', 'GuestController');
});

/*** AUTHENTICATION ***/
Route::group(array('before' => 'guest'), function()
{
    Route::get( '/assinar',                'AuthController@signup'        );
    Route::post('/assinar',                'AuthController@signupHandler' );
    Route::get( '/minha-conta',            'AuthController@login'         );
    Route::post('/minha-conta',            'AuthController@loginHandler'  );
    Route::get( '/franquia',               'AuthController@login'         );
    Route::post('/franquia',               'AuthController@loginHandler'  );
});
Route::group(array(), function()
{
    Route::any( '/minha-conta/logout',     'AuthController@logout'               );
    Route::any( '/confirmar/{code}',       'AuthController@verify'               );
    Route::get( '/solicitar-senha',        'AuthController@forgotPassword'       );
    Route::post( '/solicitar-senha',       'AuthController@forgotPasswordHandler');
    Route::any( '/recuperar-senha/{code}', 'AuthController@resetPassword'        )->where('code', '(.*)');
    Route::any( '/franquia/logout',        'AuthController@logout'               );
});

/*** "LOGGED-IN USER" SITE  ***/
Route::controller('minha-conta', 'AssinanteController');
Route::controller('franquia', 'FranquiaController');

/*** SPECIAL ROUTES ***/
Route::group(array(), function()
{
    // Use these routes while in local/development environment to see
    // how these exceptional pages look like in the production environment

    Route::get('/404', function()
    {
        return Response::view('special.missing', array(), 404);
    });

    Route::get('/500', function()
    {
        return Response::view('special.error', array('error' => 'Erro desconhecido'), 500);
    });

    Route::get('/down', function()
    {
        return Response::view('special.down', array(), 503);
    });
});
```

Como se pode ver, o grosso do site está aqui, nestas poucas e simples linhas:

```
/*** "LOGGED-IN USER" SITE  ***/
Route::controller('minha-conta', 'AssinanteController');
Route::controller('franquia', 'FranquiaController');
```

Concordo com as outras respostas: é preciso manter a organização, e é preciso seguir um padrão coerente - seu e/ou da equipe.